# R: Getting Second Value After Grouping and Summarizing

Tags: r, dplyr

Various R functions make it easy to use group_by and summarize to pull a value from a grouped variable. So in the resulting dataframe, I can use group_by and summarise to create, for example, a new column that contains the maximum or minimum value of a variable within each group. Meaning, with this data:

```
name, value
foo, 100
foo, 200
foo, 300
bar, 400
bar, 500
bar, 600
```

I can easily get the max or min for each value of name:

```
group_by(name) %>% summarize(maxValue = max(value)
```

But suppose I want the second ranked value for each name? Meaning suppose I want my result to be

```
name maxValue secondValue
foo 300 200
bar 600 500
```

In other words, how do I fill in the blank in this:

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% 
summarize(maxValue = max(value), 
  secondValue = _________)
```

Thanks, from an r newbie, for any help!

Comment: I know your previous question was closed as a duplicate, but it would be better to edit that original question than to post a new question. So I'll re-open the previous question, please delete this one.

Comment: @neilfws: I don't see my closed question in my list of asked questions, so I don't see how to edit the reopened question.  Sorry, not terribly experienced on SO.  2) Why was it closed in the first place?  I had stated specifically in that post why the prior post someone referred to did not in fact answer my question, and I had edited my question to be specific about why the earlier post did not solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you, everyone.  Suggestions worked, and are much appreciated.  BTW, I actually solved my problem a third way, which was to use rank() to create an ordered ranking within each group, and then using which() to pull out data associated with a record at a specific rank within the group.

Answer (score 2):

dplyr has the handy `nth()` function to extract the nth element out of the list.

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% 
   summarize(maxValue = max(value), 
             secondValue =nth(value, 2, order_by = value))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach, excluding the max value from the second calculation.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(maxValue = max(value), 
    secondValue = max(value[which.max(value) != row_number()]))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  name  maxValue secondValue
  <chr>    <int>       <int>
1 bar        600         500
2 foo        300         200
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar"
), value = c(100, 400, 300, 400, 500, 600)), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```